# How to fix javascript not sending any req.body to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, python-requests, body-parser

I m not getting any req.body parameters. Its working perfectly fine while posting with postman
Code:

```
async function postRequest(url, data){

    const response = await axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    return response.data
  }
```

server side:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

I use this before adding any app.get functions.

Any help would be appreciated.
FYI I use reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the content type to json but your server is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You should set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
async function postRequest(url, data){

    const response = await axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    })
    return response.data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
'''
app.use(bodyParser.json())
'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).